# Wireless card showing in one place and not another?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, server

I'm having a strange problem that I haven't been able to find an answer to after a few hours of Google. Ubuntu server version 12.04.

lspci -v shows my wireless card, as such:

```
Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02)
Subsystem: Linksys WMP54GS v1.1 802.11g Wireless-G PCI Adapter with SpeedBooster
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
Memory at fe9fc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
Kernel modules: ssb
```

However, ifconfig shows:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:12:3f:d4:6c:d2
          inet addr:192.168.2.14  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::212:3fff:fed4:6cd2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:318642 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36376 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:89728370 (89.7 MB)  TX bytes:7303647 (7.3 MB)
          Interrupt:17

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

and iwconfig shows:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

How do I get my wireless card to be shown as a valid network adapter for the network configuration commands? The computer is clearly reading it, as per lspci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to function properly, your card requires firmware. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

It may take a reboot.

Comment: This got it to show up properly in iwconfig. Thanks!